# I don't understand how to work with the Lazy Models in AWS Amplify Datastore

Tags: typescript, graphql, aws-amplify, datastore

When working with data models, I have to use `async` and `await` which I'm a little unsure about. But I have a `client`. I look up the needed clientIDs, then retrieve the Client model from DataStore.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            let clients: Client[] = [];
            let bookings: LazyBooking[] = [];
            let Inquiries: LazyInquiry[] = []; // TODO add logic to get inquiries

            // filter by tutor id
            if (tutorId) {
                bookings.concat(await DataStore.query(Booking, (c) => c.bookingTutorId.eq(tutorId)))
            // admin, get all clients
            } else {
                bookings.concat(await DataStore.query(Booking))
            }
                
            // resolve the client Id into the client names
            for await (const booking of bookings) {
                let clientId = booking.bookingClientId;
                if (clientId !== undefined && clientId !== null) {
                    let client = await DataStore.query(Client, (c) => c.id.eq(clientId!));
                    clients.push(await client)
                }
            }

            setAllclients(clients);
        }
        
        getData();
    }, [tutorId])
```

My error comes with pushing the client object onto the list. I get the error:

```
let client: LazyClient[]
Argument of type 'LazyClient[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LazyClient'.
  Type 'LazyClient[]' is missing the following properties from type 'LazyClient': id, firstName, lastName, authToken, and 5 more.ts(2345)
```

I understand that `LazyClient` is not the same as `Client`, but I feel like I've tried awaiting, then(), and other things to get Lazyclient to load into a Client model so I can save it to state.
Here are the three examples that AWS gives in their documentation.
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/relational/q/platform/js/#querying-relations
None of these examples

I could really use some help with this.